`vc-revision-*` for deleted file
I sometimes want to look at the last version of a deleted file.  Normally for a file that still exists in the repo, I cant do Ctrl+x v ~ (bound to vc-revision-other-window).  But that has no mechanism to specify a file name.
I looked at the source, there is a check like this (vc-ensure-vc-buffer).  Which means even if I could specify a file namem it would fail for a deleted file.  I also couldn't find anything in magit that provides this functionality.  Any idea if there's something, or do I need to write something custom?
Normally, I can do this in the terminal with:
$ git show <revision>:<path/to/file>


See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420282/using-emacs-and-magit-to-visit-a-file-in-given-commit-branch-etc

@phils as mentioned in my question, I'm looking for a deleted file.  Unless I'm overlooking something obvious, that's not supported by vc-revision-other-window

The link was primarily on account of the code for the custom command my-vc-visit-file-revision which, like magit-find-file, does support visiting old revisions of historical file paths which no longer exist.

I didn't look hard enough. magit-find-file does the job.
